# ¿Cómo leer una línea en específico desde un txt? JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente `BufferedReader` y `FileReader`:

```
private static final String FILENAME = "rutadelarchivo";
BufferedReader br = null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Y en archivo pone lo siguiente:

```
0.330,4879,5427,3.7,4.3,1407.6,4222.6,57.9,46.0,69.8,88.0,47.4,7.0,0.205,0.034,167,0,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,10
```

Cómo podria especificarle que lea una linea en especifico, por ejemplo la 5ta si tuviera? Porque con

```
br.readNextLine();
```

Siempre lee la primera linea y yo necesito mostrar las distintas lineas en distintos campos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `Stream` es sencillo:

```
public static final int TARGET_LINE = 5;
public static final String FILENAME = "rutadelarchivo";

...

String result;
Path filePath = Paths.get(FILENAME);

try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(filePath)) {
    result = lines.skip(TARGET_LINE - 1).findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: Y cómo funciona exactamente el stream? Lee toda la linea? Incluso lo separado por comas? No lo he usado nunca yme gustaria entender el código